# Maintaining code base for Android/iOS Hybrid Applications

Tags: javascript, angularjs, git, cordova

I am planning to develop hybrid application for Android and iOS using Angular,Phonegap etc.
My main query is how to maintain single code base for iOS/Android?

Q1:I execute cordova create command to create project for Android. and write one Hello World App.Do I need to do create project again in iOS and copy www?

Q2: How about maintaining single code in git ? I am confused since folder structure are different for Android and iOS ?
Any help is appreciated.
I have searched many blogs but didn't find the this concepts.

Comment: Why - here ? I am asking the code base stuff .. Also I see no answers if -2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Just develop your code under project/www

```
cordova platform add android
cordova platform add ios
```

Will create both platforms, and with `cordova prepare`, and `cordova build`, it will copy the files to each platform

To maintain code, just add your project into a GIT, and both platforms project/platforms/[IOS/android] will be in the same project. You can also gitignore the platforms if you want to maintain light your project

Comment: You may suggest also a .gitignore file content